# Set Cookies on subdomain?

Tags: cookies, dns, cross-domain, subdomain

I have the site blah.com. I need to set 3cookies + use google analytic. I would like to set it as www.blah.com so when i serve images (on blah.com or static.blah.com) it is cookie-less.

Is this possible? How do i do it? I am using jquery-cookies and asp.net

Comment: please explain better... do you which cookies in whick domain?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Domain set cookie for subdomain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258126/domain-set-cookie-for-subdomain)

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the domain attribute of the cookie to "www.blah.com"

Comment: It doesnt seem to work. Actually i am starting to think you can set cookies of a top domain but not subdomain.

Comment: It absolutely does work and thousands of websites rely upon it. Post your incorrect code and the community can help you fix it.

Comment: Actually someone said it DOESNT work because root sites (blah.com) doesnt receive cookies from subdomain (www.blah.com) thus i cant do it. Is that true? Are you sure i can do this?

Comment: But that's exactly what you wanted-- as you said in your problem description, you say that you want your cookies sent only to "www.blah.com" and not to "blah.com" or "static.blah.com".

Comment: I believe if you set it to '.domain.com' all subdomains can access it. (mind the initial dot)