# Domain set cookie for subdomain

Tags: http, cookies, setcookie

I looked in many questions about cookies but I didn't find an answer on my problem. I have following scenario:

A user creates a login on *example.com* and should get a cookie but only for the subdomain *fuu.example.com*. I generate following HTTP header part:

```
Set-Cookie: name=TestUser; Domain=fuu.example.com; Path=/; secure; HttpOnly
```

But when I make a request to *https://fuu.example.com*, the cookie will be not added to the request. I wonder if it is possible that *example.com* sets a cookie for `fuu.example.com`. I know that it is possible that *example.com* set a cookie for `.example.com` also for all subdomains for *example.com* but that's not what I want.

How do I set a cookie for a subdomain? I am not seeing the cookie in a request to the subdomain.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

No. <del>Besides that `fuu.example.com` is an invalid *Domain* value (it must start with a `.`, i.e. `.fuu.example.com`)</del> (see update below) the [cookie would get rejected](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109#section-4.3.2):

> To prevent possible security or privacy violations, a user agent rejects a cookie (shall not store its information) if any of the following is true:
>
> - The request-host is a Fully-Qualifed Domain Name (not IP address) and has the form *HD*, where *D* is the value of the *Domain* attribute, and *H* is a string that contains one or more dots.

The request-host is `example.com` and the *Domain* attribute value is `foo.example.com`. But the request-host `example.com` does not has the form *HD* where *D* would be `foo.example.com`. Thus the cookie gets rejected.

---

**Update**    The current specification [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265), that obsoleted RFC 2109 that is quoted above, does ignore the leading dot. But the effective domain is handled the same:

> […] if the value of the Domain attribute is
> "`example.com`", the user agent will include the cookie in the Cookie
> header when making HTTP requests to *example.com*, *[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)*, and
> *[www.corp.example.com](http://www.corp.example.com)*.  (Note that a leading %x2E ("`.`"), if present,
> is ignored even though that character is not permitted, but a
> trailing %x2E ("`.`"), if present, will cause the user agent to ignore
> the attribute.)
>
> […] the user agent will accept a cookie with a
> Domain attribute of "`example.com`" or of "`foo.example.com`" from
> *foo.example.com*, but the user agent will not accept a cookie with a
> Domain attribute of "`bar.example.com`" or of "`baz.foo.example.com`".

Answer (score 24):

The 2 domains `example.com` and `foo.example.com` can only share cookies if the domain is explicitly named in the Set-Cookie header. Otherwise, the scope of the cookie is restricted to the request host.

For instance, if you sent the following header from `foo.example.com`:

```
Set-Cookie: name=value
```

Then the cookie won't be sent for requests to `example.com`. However if you use the following, it will be usable on both domains:

```
Set-Cookie: name=value; domain=example.com
```

In RFC 2109, a domain without a leading dot meant that it could not be used on subdomains, and only a leading dot (`.example.com`) would allow it to be used across subdomains.

However, modern browsers respect the newer specification RFC 6265, and will ignore any leading dot, meaning you can use the cookie on subdomains as well as the top-level domain.

**In summary**, if you set a cookie like the second example above from `example.com`, it would be accessible by `foo.example.com`, and vice versa.

For more details : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23086139/5466401

Comment: What about sharing cookie between `foo1.example.com` and `foo2.example.com`? Is that possible without `foo3.example.com` getting it?

Comment: Have you got any solution for the same @DushyantBangal

Comment: @PranavBilurkar from the R&D I did, the server can only set a cookie for itself which is applicable `foo2.example.com` or its wildcard subdomain applicable for `*.foo2.example.com`.

Comment: @PranavBilurkar ... so to implement what I've mentioned, one will have to call API on both `foo1.example.com` and `foo2.example.com`, and they will set their respective cookies.

Comment: actually my problem is " I have 7 sites with `.example.com` which shares the cookie on all sites & i want to exclude to have shared cookie on `media.example.com`

Comment: @sibin Would it be recommended (and safe) to do something like a auth server like that? For example, I have a service `service.example.com` and a login page at `example.com`. Then, by setting a cookie at `example.com` when the user logs in, I will be able use that cookie from `service.example.com`. Is that fine? You can take that I have no other program using that `example.com` auth server.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is a simple and fully cross-browser support way for sharing cookies between original domain and subdomains but you should share it in setting time, for comfortable working with cookie stuffs in browser I'm using [`js-cookie`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie) and with the below setting cookie it could be shared between original domain and all of its subdomains:

```js
Cookie.set('key', 'value', { domain: '.domain.com' })

// a . added before domain name
```

*Hint*: Adding this `.` will share cookie with all sub-subdomain.