# Setting cookie for subdomain with php won't work

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie from "example.com" so that it's only accessible to 'site.example.com'. The problem is that this does not work for some reason. 
For example, the code below works correctly:

```
setcookie('my_var', "hello", time()+3600, "/", 'example.com');
```

That is, when ran from example.com, then I can see the 'my_var' cookie from the site.example.com. However, the code below does not set the cookie:

```
setcookie('my_var', "hello", time()+3600, "/", 'site.example.com');
```

(neither does if I prepend a dot, like '.site.example.com')

Using php 5.3.8 and chromium

Comment: You'll might find if you inspect the headers on your request that the cookie header is being sent, but your browser is ignoring it

Comment: You can’t set a cookie for a sub domain, only for the same or a super domain.

Comment: @gumbo: you mean that I can set a cookie from site.example.com to be accessible for example.com, but not the other way?

Comment: @periklis Yes, exactly. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/5258477/53114.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Domain set cookie for subdomain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258126/domain-set-cookie-for-subdomain)

Comment: I see, thanks. Do you know if there's a RFC or something where this is described? why don't you post this as an answer so I can set it as replied

Comment: @periklis I’ve already posted a link to the corresponding RFC and updated the post only just to comply with the recent RFC update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gumbo noted in his comment, you can’t set a cookie for a sub domain, only for the same or a super domain, see [Domain set cookie for subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258126/domain-set-cookie-for-subdomain)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was trying to set a cookie **from sd1.example.com** to work on example.com, www.example.com, sd2.example.com etc.

I tried changing some settings in php.ini, explicitly listing all subdomains, but none worked. I realized that only the root domain can set cookies on other subdomains and one subdomain cannot set a cookie on another.

So I made a script **setcookie.php** on the root domain, i.e. **example.com**

sd1.example.com sends a GET request to this script:

```
header("Location: //example.com/setcookie.php?value=" . $xxxxx);
```

And in **setcookie.php**

```
setcookie("xxxxx", $_GET['value'], 0, "/", ".example.com");
```

This way the cookie can be accessed from all subdomains by default.