# Http Authentication: Global user login

Tags: apache, nginx, http-authentication, .htpasswd

I have several subdomains, some of them protected by HTTP authentication (htpasswd). Is there a way to login to all subdomains once the user login to one of them?

Comment: Does this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258126/domain-set-cookie-for-subdomain answer your question?

Comment: As far as I understand HTTP authentication via htpasswd, it is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Surely authenticated sessions will be given cookies? Making the cookie also work for other subdomains will mean the user won't have to login again.

Comment: from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication: `HTTP Basic authentication (BA) implementation is the simplest technique for enforcing access controls to web resources because it doesn't require cookies, session identifier and login pages.`