# Cookie is not sent with JavaScript on POST request

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

I want to use a secure cookie which is stored by the browser when accessing the endpoint `/access` on my website. The cookie is saved during the login process and I made sure that my website runs on a subdomain of my backend (which creates the cookies for the clients).

My backend is running on `www.welovecoding.com` and my web application is hosted on `webapp.welovecoding.com`.

The cookie which I receive from my backend looks like this:

> Set-Cookie:user_id=RLXXWNCGAyVBmnogfiE1ngFCpBRKA48YaFOGyrPypwvU3eZCA==;
>   Path=/access; Expires=Tue, 29-Sep-2015 17:37:11 GMT;
>   Domain=.welovecoding.com; HttpOnly; Secure

What I want to do now is a POST request on `www.welovecoding.com/access` with my cookie as authentication credentials. I am sending `withCredentials` when executing my AJAX request with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  crossDomain: true,
  type: 'POST',
  url: "http://www.welovecoding.com/access",
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  }
}).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  console.log("Response", data);
});
```

But I still do get a HTTP error 403 which says that the cookie is missing. Does anyone know why? Maybe because the cookie has `HttpOnly` and `Secure` set?

Comment: Are you sure your cookie is not rejected? According to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258126/domain-set-cookie-for-subdomain) it should be rejected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's because the cookie has `Secure` set - and you are posting to `http`

```
;secure (cookie to only be transmitted over secure protocol as https)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie

Comment: You're right! I forgot to mention that I also tested from HTTPS to HTTPS. But it did not work. Do I miss anything else?

Comment: Try removing the `xhrFields:{withCredentials:true}` as it's used for cross-domain requests

Comment: also if you "are" doing cross domain - you need to set the appropriate preflight cors headers http://www.staticapps.org/articles/cross-domain-requests-with-cors

Comment: Ok, I accepted your answer as my description was pointing to the fact that HTTPS is missing. By the way, do I have to store the cookie with JavaScript or will it be saved automatically by the browser when receiving it as "Set-Cookie" parameter?

Comment: it will automatically create the cookie for you - And since HttpOnly is also passed - `If the HttpOnly flag (optional) is included in the HTTP response header, the cookie cannot be accessed through client side script (again if the browser supports this flag).` https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly

Comment: So was the main issue setting the cors headers?

Comment: Thanks for your support. With your help I solved the problem. I had to run on HTTPS because of the "secure" property in the cookie (as you mentioned). But I also needed to send "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true" with the cookie from the backend. And what was very surprising... I had to use the "xhrFields" in my request for the login (which gives me the cookie) and the actual request where I want to send that cookie back. So it works now! Thank you very much. :)