# Cookies on cross domain requests

Tags: javascript, cookies, cross-domain

I have a web app hosted on domain.com and it has a registration form.

When the user completes the registration form the web app calls an Api hosted on app.domain.com.

The Api is a POST request, called using JavaScript's XmlHttpRequest and the response includes a Set-Cookie header.

However when I inspect the cookies present for app.domain.com the cookie received on the Api request is on present.

I thought the browser would handle cookies automatically and since the request to the app.domain.com returns a Set-Cookie header the browser would include the cookie in all subsequent requests to app.domain.com.

**Api request**:

```
Request URL:https://app.domain.com/api/account/subscribe
Request Method:POST
```

**Api Response**

```
Set-Cookie:.AspNet.ExternalBearer=DlOvLGlPLlMWO4mXUcH9ieWNSTpRZ80hhWEKXrFUN-BOfwUsVu4x4qNXizpvdRWA4eIyijsmQARICLPOC-spzXjEVzz-WvO2ZsnSR30kM65dpkALqCUn2OgU2Zqc-fF5mESeYCEDeBCbHuSedCNqWfCIUX3mbeoI3vMu1086YwsinlnUkGe4gC9Ggk44N0PPuoh3J1xl85zUVhd9AsoaUspPzX2zlzkPmJMyb3shx9VlE8dx0ePQLuQhbHfnQdt8L5I5W9NK8uM3lJtHWKvR5lszd7AyuMDmX1N_MA7fGRAHCsW8FcCCvzeM9oH3c5zZU0uLKQKT5NZF8QyUdDGq6H6U5dPhm5FLTmsCw3qfLGXvIbO8uu-9p__VdEmvgr60D78uWrg6K-akNYNQDHVWvNyVdOYwM8N2H3l0hiTV8GveiZV-WpI4VSGFoOr821H8PRj1eC6UT6GiTFeksp7JmFLKuVLx8YY6uLcQYldQQUKDnvSiteZbwVg-DSYnGW9FdN3t9AdbUaW3mjFTCz_of5utAO9Fl8TFS02GucZLMCFEfxBkHh9qcmWUMrauWOLl59huTAFYDoCGG9pi06Hvm7ggF3H4oP-fXyFe85AsRC4; domain=app.domain.com; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
```

No cookie is included in the subsequent request to app.domain.com

So, what's missing?

Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

Comment: I'm not trying to include the cookie the request to www.app.domain.com but instead setting a cookie based on the response of a request to www.app.domain.com

Comment: _"In addition, this flag is also used to indicate when cookies are to be ignored in the response."_

Comment: CBroe, how can I thank you? :) Please answer the question so I can mark it as accepted! Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the withCredentials flag for cookies to properly work when making cross-domain requests.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials:

> In addition, this flag is also used to indicate when cookies are to be ignored in the response.

Answer (score -2):

You have to explicitly set domain in the cookie.

`Set-Cookie: name=value; domain=domain.com`

Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258126/domain-set-cookie-for-subdomain) for more details.

Comment: Cool Jakub! Indeed having a look at the headers the domain is not being set. Let me try it and I will get back to you! Thanks