# Setting Cookies for CloudFront

Tags: cookies, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a CloudFront distribution running on a CNAME

> cdn.xxx.domain.com

The app is running on

> xxx.domain.com

The main app is creating three cookies for the domain `cdn.xxx.domain.com`

- CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id
- CloudFront-Signature
- CloudFront-Policy

But when I visit `cdn.xxx.domain.com` the cookies are not present.

And I get the error

> Missing Key-Pair-Id query parameter or cookie value

Because the cookies are not present.

I have also sent the CloudFront instance to forward all Cookies.

The origin is S3. If I turn off Restrict Viewer Access (Use Signed URLs or Signed Cookies) - then I can access the resource. So the URL I am using is correct.

Why can the `cnd.` subdomain not use the cookies? You can see here - they are being set in the response from the main app. Using the CDN domain.

[image: cookies set]

Only 2 cookies shown in the image, but there are 3.

Comment: *"You can see here..."*  I only see two cookies.  There should be three.  `CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id` is missing.

Comment: It is there, it is just not in the image

Comment: The error is specifically complaining about the one that is not shown. Next, you say *"because the cookies are not present*", which seems to imply that you have confirmed that *none* of them are being sent with the request, as observed from the browser developer tools.  Confirm this?

Comment: Yes, none of them are present on the cdn domain

Comment: It looks as if you can't explicitly set a cookie for a subdomain from higher up in the hierarchy. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/5258477/1695906

Comment: Ohhhh, thanks I will try this...

Comment: I have changed the CloudFront domain to `cdn.domain.com` and set the domain for the cookies to `.domain.com` and now they are being read. Thanks for that! But now I get Access Denied from CloudFront. No other errors.

Comment: Is the Access Denied error XML? If no, then that error might not be from CloudFront rejecting your cookies, and I'll need to see the error.  Does the XML include a `<RequestId>`?  If yes, then that isn't from CloudFront, it's from S3, and the Origin Access Identity is the problem, not the cookies.  Otherwise, I'll need to see your policy statement.

Comment: Ahhh. Sorted it! The URL I was using to access the resource was slightly different from that in the policy. Thanks Michael!